# How to useState() properly in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple increment app where you hit a button and the count increments by 1.

My question is: how do I update the state properly?

Here are the two ways I am wondering between and of course if there is any other "better" option please do tell me.

```
import React, {useState} from "react"

const App = ()  => {   
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    
    const increment = () => {
        setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>The count is {count}</h1>
            <button onClick={increment}>Add 1</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

or

```
import React, {useState} from "react"

const App = ()  => {   
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    
    const increment = () => {
        setCount(count + 1)
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>The count is {count}</h1>
            <button onClick={increment}>Add 1</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Which one is the best way of updating the state and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine a case as follows, and you'll mean the difference:

```
const increment = () => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
}
```

Or:

```
const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1)
    setCount(count + 1)
}
```

Not the same behavior.

Comment: interesting, then it would be wiser to use the first option i guess?

Comment: it depends: what should be the expected behavior of your app? if it was a shopping cart, as a user, I wouldn't like that an accidental click more leads to an extra item in the basket. Thus, I'd see the second approach better (as a principle). Instead, for a component which scales a picture (every click inc/dec the zoom), the first approach seems the more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

usually when use useCallback, it's better to use setCount(x=> x + 1);

```js
const onIncr = React.useCallback(()=> {
  setCount(x=> x + 1)
}, [])
```

vs

```js
const onIncr = React.useCallback(()=> {
   setCount(count + 1)
}, [count])
```

tips , this example can transform into

```
const [count, increment] = React.useReducer((x)=> x + 1, 0);
return <button onClick={increment}>{count}</button>
```

This technique is usually used in toggle value

```
const [isOpen, toggle] = React.useReducer(x=> !x, false);
return (
<>
  <button onClick={toggle}>open dialog</button>
  <Dialog open={isOpen} onClose={toggle}></Dialog>
<>
 )
```